# Creating mathjax-style documents

Tags: html, mathjax, latex2html, mathml

Is there any software, website, etc. that renders a document as if MathJax were being used, but in such a way that the output can be read by someone who is not using MathJax? (Perhaps the equations and notation could be inserted as png images.) I'm not sure what format the output document should be; perhaps html, or rtf in the unlikely event that that is possible. Here are my motivations:

1. It's all very well to use GmailTeX to apply MathJax to emails I am reading or writing, but sometimes I send emails to people whom I know do not use this feature. I would like to be able to send them emails that I know they can read, without having to attach a pdf or include images by hand.
2. LaTeX has a fairly steep learning curve. It would be nice to have a way for students who want to communicate math by computer to concentrate only on typing the math, without having to learn about non-WYSIWYG typesetting, compiling, etc.

Chances are, what I am asking for is impossible without a revision of web standards or some such. But if there are any options that do anything like this, I would like to know about them.

Comment: Depending on the size of your LaTeX snippets, you could consider the `standalone` package to render them as individual graphics and put those into your document. LaTeXiT and other similar equation editors are also a good route to doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what you ask for doesn't need a revision of the web standards.  What you need is better implementation of the *existing* standards.
[MathML](http://www.w3.org/MathML) is the web standard for communicating mathematics.  However, it is not universally supported (Firefox is good, IE works with a plugin, other browsers are ... not so good).  Indeed, MathJaX is a bridge allowing MathML on browsers that don't support it.

For generating it, take a look at the list of [converters](http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/mathml_software_cat_converters.html) on the w3 webpages.  Tex4HT is The Big One for converting TeX documents.  I recommend itextomml for shorter maths segments (it's what is used on the [nlab](http://ncatlab.org), for example).

Answer (score 0):

## Auto-Latex Equations for Google Docs

Yup, the easiest one by far is Google Docs, which can save as RTF as you requested. To do this, all that is needed is the [Auto-Latex Equations add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=stackOverflow21), which renders math right in a Google Doc.

All you have to do is type an equation within standard LaTeX delimiters, like $$55 + \sqrt{5}$$ and it can be rendered in at whatever time you like by rendering all the equations in your document. If you mess up, you can always undo them, edit them, then re-render them. You can get it at [the Docs add-on store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=stackOverflow21). Although this thread is years old, I hope this still is useful for someone!